# Rails 4 Session across subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, subdomain

I'm trying the following with no luck in an attempt to persist sessions across subdomains:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', :domain => :all, :tld_length => 2

MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', :domain => 'myapp.dev'

MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', :domain => '.myapp.dev'
```

I found all of these combinations on Google and SO.

I saw a few explanations but it involved manually setting the cookie.  I'd like to stick with configuration if possible.

Note: I'm using devise.  I've also restarted the server and cleared cookies.

Comment: The first one should work and is my preferred way to go. Did you try changing the cookie key while testing? I've used this as a "hard reset" in the past.

Comment: changing the cookie while testing?  with chrome dev tools or firebug?

Comment: I said the cookie key, so changing `_myapp_session` to `_myapp_tmp` for instance. Just to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 1):

I found that different applications should have identical `secret_key_base`, located in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`. After I did this, all my applications is started to use shared session.

PS. Of course, they should have identical session keys.