# Rails: Using Devise Across Multiple Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app set up with a main domain and multiple subdomains.  I have `devise` up and working on the main domain, but when I enter `subdomain.domain.com` whatever session is currently on the domain is not recognized.  I have seen and tried the answers found in [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402777/share-session-cookies-between-subdomains-in-rails) (also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262462/rails-4-session-across-subdomains)) and [blogs](http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/) alike, but nothing seems to be working.

I am working with my `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file and have tried:

```
Bdc::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bdc_session', domain: lvh.me, tld_length: 2
```

I have tried the following permutations as well:

- `domain: :all`
- `tld_length: '1'`
- No `tld_length` listed

None of these have worked.  I am using Rails 4.2.5 and devise 4.0.  Can anyone help me get to the point where I can have the same session persist from `domain.com` to `subdomain1.domain.com`, `subdomain2.domain.com`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
Bdc::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bdc_session', domain: .lvh.me, tld_length: 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for this I get an error when I try to start the server `session_store.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
... key: '_bdc_session', domain: .lvh.me, tld_length: 2
...                               ^
`

Comment: If I use quotes around `".lvh.me" the server starts, but it still does not recognize a session in my subdomain.

Comment: or try config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_domain_session', :domain => :all

Comment: Actually, after using this for a bit, this caused [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667563/activerecordstatementinvalid-sqlite3ioexception-disk-i-o-error) error.  Can you opine?

Comment: Also, the version you suggested made the devise not register sessions due to CSRF token authenticity issues...

Comment: What ended up working was `Bdc::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bdc_session', domain: ".domain.com"`, which didn't cause the funky error.